# Make Initialization Asynchronous in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to initialize a key class in a node.js program, but the instructions are running in arbitrary order and therefore it is initializing wrong. I've tried both making initialization happen in the definition and in a separate function; neither works. Is there something that I'm missing?

Current code:

```
class BotState {
    constructor() {
        this.bios = {}
        this.aliases = {};
        this.stories = {};
        this.nextchar = 0;
    }
}

var ProgramState = new BotState();

BotState.prototype.Initialize = function() {
    this.bios = {};
    var aliases = {};
    var nextchar = 0;
    this.nextchar = 0;
    fs.readdir(biosdir, function (err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var file in files) {
            fs.readFile(biosdir + file + ".json", {flag: 'r'}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                var bio = JSON.parse(data);
                var index = bio["charid"];
                this.bios[index] = bio;
                for (var alias in bio["aliaslist"]) {
                    this.aliases[bio["aliaslist"][alias].toLowerCase()] = index;
                }
                if (index >= nextchar) {
                    nextchar = index + 1;
                }
            })
        }
        this.stories = {};
        this.nextchar = Math.max(Object.keys(aliases).map(key => aliases[key]))+1;
    });
}

ProgramState.Initialize();
```

Is there some general way to make node.js just... run commands in the order they're written, as opposed to some arbitrary one?

(Apologies if the code is sloppy; I was more concerned with making it do the right thing than making it look nice.)

Comment: Use `fs.promises.readFile()` and then `await` its result in your loop.  That will allow the loop to run in sequence.

Comment: And, don't every write `if (err) throw err;` inside a plain asynchronous  callback as it does absolutely nothing useful and cannot be caught by any of your code.  It's basically worthless other than a partial abort of your loop.  You can't detect or handle the error in any structured way.  Write proper error handling.

Comment: Also, never use `for (var file in files)` to iterate an array.  Use `for (let file of files)`.  `in` iterates properties which can include more than just array elements.  `of` used with an array iterates only array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are running an asynchronous operation in a loop which causes the loop to continue running and the asynchronous operations finish in some random order so you process them in some random order.  The simplest way to control your loop is to switch to the promise-based version of the `fs` library and then use `async/await` to cause your `for` loop to pause and wait for the asynchronous operation to complete.  You can do that like this:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

class BotState {
    constructor() {
        this.bios = {}
        this.aliases = {};
        this.stories = {};
        this.nextchar = 0;
    }
}

var ProgramState = new BotState();

BotState.prototype.Initialize = async function() {
    this.bios = {};
    this.nextchar = 0;

    let aliases = {};
    let nextchar = 0;
    const files = await fsp.readdir(biosdir);

    for (const file of files) {
        const data = await fsp.readFile(biosdir + file + ".json", {flag: 'r'});
        const bio = JSON.parse(data);
        const index = bio.charid;
        const list = bio.aliaslist;
        this.bios[index] = bio;
        for (const alias of list) {
            this.aliases[alias.toLowerCase()] = index;
        }
        if (index >= nextchar) {
            nextchar = index + 1;
        }
    }

    this.stories = {};
    // there is something wrong with this line of code because you NEVER
    // put any  data in the variable aliases
    this.nextchar = Math.max(Object.keys(aliases).map(key => aliases[key]))+1;
}

ProgramState.Initialize();
```

Note, there's a problem with your usage of the `aliases` local variable because you never put anything in that data structure, yet you're trying to use it in the last line of the function.  I don't know what you're trying to accomplish there so you will have to fix that.

Also, note that you should never use `for/in` to iterate an array.  That iterates properties of an object which can include more than just the array elements.  `for/of` is made precisely for iterating an iterable like an array and it also saves the array dereference too as it gets you each value, not each index.

Comment: @Frosty - Did this answer your question?