# Javascript order of execution using Node fs functions

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have been trying to get the following code to do as I would like it to. That is print `1 2 3` to the console.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const doSomthingWithFile = (file, number) => {
  fs.readFile(file, () => {
    console.log(number);
  });
};

fs.readdir('./', (err, files) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    doSomthingWithFile(files[i], 1);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    doSomthingWithFile(files[i], 2);
  }
});

console.log(3);
```

I have been trying to use async/await and functions that return promises but I am guessing I am doing it all wrong as I keep getting `3 1 2` as output.

How would I make sure it all executes in the order I would like it to. That means first read the directory. Then wait until the first `doSomthingWithFile()` finishes before starting the second one and waiting with the last log statement until the `readdir()` callback has finished?

Like I said I have been trying to search around on this site mainly for similar topics but still can't manage to get it to work. For example, making the callback async functions and awaiting the functions inside it did not work (or I must have been doing it incorrectly).

Comment: `async/await and functions that retun promises` - Well this would be how to do it, but your example doesn't show any indication of this. Can you share your attempts?

Comment: You need to perform the iteration in an async way such that the next iteration won't be triggered until the previous is complete. I'd recommend using a recursive-style while loop.

Comment: Very similar question and my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745651/make-initialization-asynchronous-in-node-js/59762042#59762042.  It was solved there by using promises `fs.promises.readdir()` and `fs.promises.readFile()` and `async/await`.  And, there are over a hundred duplicate questions/answers here on stackoverflow for asynchronous operations in a loop.  Super common question.

Comment: @JacobPenney how would you perform an iteration in a async way?

Comment: @jfriend00 going to take a loot at it right now.

Comment: @jfriend00 it seems like he is missing the event loop mechanism and how javascript work under the hood

Comment: can you do it using `fs` sync methods?

Comment: Did you read that other answer I referenced?  It shows you how to do it there.  Same kind of iteration too.

Comment: @jfriend00 just tried it. Seems to work in my minimal exaple at least. Going to try to add it to my codebase now. See if my example was representative enough. However it does throw a warning saying fs.promises is experimental.

Comment: What version of node.js are you running?  Maybe need to upgrade because it's not experimental any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be synchronous, use synchronous methods (`fs.readdirSync` and `fs.readFileSync`). Below is `async/await` version:

```js
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

const doSomthingWithFile = async (file, number) => {
  await fsp.readFile(file);
  console.log(number);
};

(async () => { // ugly async iife since global await is not supported yet

  const files = await fsp.readdir('./');

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    await doSomthingWithFile(files[i], 1);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    await doSomthingWithFile(files[i], 2);
  }

  console.log(3);
})();
```

Comment: FYI, I'd suggest doing `const fsp = require('fs').promises` and then refer to `fsp` instead of `fs` so readers of your code know that it's not the standard `fs` that people might be used to, but the promises version.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your doSomethignWithFile function return a promise, you can await it such that the next iteration will **never** be performed until the previous has resolved. Something like this should work:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const doSomthingWithFile = (file, number) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile(file, () => {
    console.log(number)
    resolve()
  });
});

fs.readdir('./', async (err, files) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    await doSomthingWithFile(files[i], 1);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    await doSomthingWithFile(files[i], 2);
  }
});
```

What's happening here:

- readdir callback made async
- doSomthingWithFile function returns a promise that resolves when the asynchronous readFile function has completed. We do that by calling the `resolve` method in the readFile function's callback.
- await the returns from the doSomthingWithFile calls. This ensures the order in which the operations happen is consistent.

Comment: No point in manually promisifying `fs` functions when `fs.promises` contains already promisified methods built-in.

Comment: I've never used fs.promises, but that sounds fine. This is a generally applicable solution that works too.

Comment: Well, it's worth learning since it's the future of the `fs` module.  There's also a much better object oriented file handle (the original `fs` filehandle was strangely just a procedural implementation of the standard library functions rather than thinking of the problem as an object with methods.  Yes, manually promisifying works, but it's no longer the recommended way.

Comment: Why is it no longer the recommended way? Because it takes a few more lines to write? Does `fs.promises` solve this problem of the strange file handle present in `fs`? How so?

Comment: Because it's the built-in way of doing things that allows you to manage your control flow and error handling of all file operations entirely with promises.  Why would you recommend to someone that they manually promisify when the promisified version is already present and you just have to use it.  Why wouldn't you want to teach someone the quicker, shorter, built-in way?  And, once they know  about `fs.promises`, they can then see all the other things you can use it for.  I don't know what you mean by "strange file handle present in fs".

Comment: I'm suggesting a way you could improve your answer (make it better) and making sure the OP knows there's a built-in way to do this now.  You can choose to ignore me if you want - I hope the OP doesn't ignore it and learns.  I didn't downvote you.  I made a suggestion for how you could make your answer better.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't know about OP or the answerer but I've certainly found your comment useful, so thanks for it :)

Comment: So it's native which would mean it's stable and requires less code to implement. Essentially, it's already implemented so no need to implement it yourself. The OP should use that, I'm all for it. It can also be useful to know how to promisify in case there is no native implementation, though.

Comment: @JacobPenney - Yes, knowing how to promisify is useful.  I personally would use `util.promisify()` for that except in rare cases where the callback signature is different than normal.